# How can one prevent excess JS event handlers in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, performance, events

#### Problem

An application requires the inner size of the window. React patterns suggests registering an event listener within a one-time effect hook. The call to `window.addEventListener` appears to occur only once, but event listeners pile up and negatively affect performance.

#### Code

Here's the pared down source code that reproduces this issue

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

const getWindowRect = () => {
  return new DOMRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

// custom hook to track the window dimensions
const useWindowRect = () => {
  // use state for the aspect ratio
  let [rect, setRect] = useState(getWindowRect);

  // useEffect w/o deps should only be called once
  useEffect(() => {
    const resizeHandler = () => { setRect(getWindowRect()); }; 
    
    window.addEventListener('resize', resizeHandler);
    console.log('added resize listener');

    // return the cleanup function
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', resizeHandler);
      console.log('removed resize listener');
    }
  }, []);

  // return the up-to-date window rect
  return rect;
}

const App = () => {
  const window_rect = useWindowRect();
  return <div>
    {window_rect.width/window_rect.height}
  </div>
};

export default App;
```

#### Testing

relevant console output reads:

```
added resize listener
```

this is the expected result where the listener is added only once, no matter how much the app is re-rendered

**reference, window not resized** max listeners: 56
[image: reference performance]

**resizing performance, hundreds of listeners accumulate** max listeners: 900+
[image: resizing performance]

**resizing performance w/ `window.addEventListener` commented out** max listeners: 49
[image: resizing performance without addEventListener]

#### Environment

- React 16.13.1
- TypeScript 4.0.3
- WebPack 4.44.2
- Babel Loader 8.1.0
- Chrome 86.0.4240.111 (Official Build) (x86_64)

#### Demo

Assuming is would be difficult to run performance metrics on a JSFiddle or CodePen I've provided a full demo at this repo: [oclyke-exploration/resize-handler-performance](https://github.com/oclyke-exploration/resize-handler-performance) You can easily run the demo as long as you have node and yarn installed.

#### General Discussion

- this approach has worked before w/o these symptoms, however the environment was slightly different and did not include TypeScript (could this be caused by the cross-compilation?)
- i've briefly looked into whether the function reference that is provided to `window.removeEventListener` is the same as that provided to `window.addEventListener` - though this should not even come into play when the effect only occurs once
- there are many possible ways to work around this issue - this question is intended to ask why this method, which is expected to work, does not
- reproduced this issue on a fresh `create-react-app` project using react-scripts 4.0.0

#### Ask

Does anyone have an explanation for this issue? I'm stumped!
(related: can others reproduce this issue?)

Comment: Won't fix the problem, but tip: change `useState<DOMRect>(getWindowRect());` to `useState(getWindowRect);` so as not to call `DOMRect` every render. Could also declare that function outside the component to avoid creating it anew every render.

Comment: I'm not sure if this would fix, but you can try defining `resizeHandler` is the main hook body and memoizing it with `useCallback`. That way there should only be the one event listener, whose reference is saved. EDIT: I assume that you've verified that the effect is only running once

Comment: @CertainPerformance thanks for the lazy initialization of ```rect``` tip! For others here's a succinct explanation of [lazy initialization in useState](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-usestate-hook-guide/#3-lazy-initialization-of-state)

Comment: @Jayce444 that's a neat idea - I've never used ```useCallback``` before! I had lightly tested that the reference remains the same w/o that hook, and that the effect really is only called once. I will update the question to reflect that.

Comment: Try moving `const resizeHandler = () => { setRect(getWindowRect()); }; ` _inside_ the `useEffect()`. **edit** ah, I didn't notice that was the case in your initial question. It should be inside though, according to React documentation.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts good catch, no point to recreate that function every render. updated

Comment: I don't think the problem is related to your code, it looks like the event handlers are registered by `invokeGuardedCallbackDev` in `react-dom.development.js`. It also looks like [they're cleaned up after long enough](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToXvE.png)

Comment: Looks like this happens only in dev mode

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/shared/invokeGuardedCallbackImpl.js#L45

Comment: Well well well... I knew there would be some smart people out there who could set me straight. Just tested in production mode and in fact this removes those symptoms. Thanks a ton PatrickRoberts and Aleksey L.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Patrick Roberts and Aleksey L. in comments on the question the issue is not actually an issue because:

- the event handlers are registered by `invokeGuardedCallbackDev` in `react-dom.development.js`
- the event handlers are [cleaned up periodically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToXvE.png)
- this [does not affect production builds](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/shared/invokeGuardedCallbackImpl.js#L45)